# How to determine the the semantic of the ACPI "control methods"?

Tags: firmware, acpi

I am new to the ACPI technology. So far, I understand that ACPI defines some `control methods` which can be used to manipulate the devices on motherboard.

I tried the `acpiexec.exe` from the ACPICA. And dumped many control methods as below:

```
\_SB.PCI0.EHC1._STA Method       77f351d0 01 Args 0 Len 000F Aml 78aa8b77
\_SB.PCI0.EHC1._RMV Method       77f35290 01 Args 0 Len 0002 Aml 78aa8b8d
\_SB.PCI0.EHC1._PR3 Method       77f352d0 01 Args 0 Len 0008 Aml 78aa8b96
\_SB.PCI0.SBUS.SSXB Method       77f34cd0 01 Args 2 Len 00A4 Aml 78aa8bd2
\_SB.PCI0.SBUS.SRXB Method       77f34d90 01 Args 1 Len 00A8 Aml 78aa8c7e
\_SB.PCI0.SBUS.SWRB Method       77f34c90 01 Args 3 Len 00AA Aml 78aa8d2e
\_SB.PCI0.SBUS.SRDB Method       77f34bd0 01 Args 2 Len 00AE Aml 78aa8de0
\_SB.PCI0.SBUS.SWRW Method       77f34dd0 01 Args 3 Len 00B8 Aml 78aa8e96
\_SB.PCI0.SBUS.SRDW Method       77f34b90 01 Args 2 Len 00BA Aml 78aa8f56
\_SB.PCI0.SBUS.SBLW Method       77f348d0 01 Args 4 Len 00FA Aml 78aa9018
\_SB.PCI0.SBUS.SBLR Method       77f346d0 01 Args 3 Len 0130 Aml 78aa911a
\_SB.PCI0.SBUS.STRT Method       77f34710 01 Args 0 Len 00AF Aml 78aa9252
```

But I don't know the semantic of each method, such as:

- What args they require?
- What action do they carry out?

I searched the [ACPI 6.0 sepc](http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/ACPI_6.0.pdf). But seems there's not a comprehensive list of all control methods as I expected. Anyone could shed some light? Thanks.

### ADD 1

Seems the ACPI 6.0 spec does cover some. I will search in it for now.

Comment: The first threes are defined in the ACPI spec you linked. The next eights are described [here](https://github.com/dtbartle/i2c-acpi-sbus), the last one may be used to send a [start condition](http://www.esacademy.com/en/library/technical-articles-and-documents/miscellaneous/i2c-bus/i2c-bus-events/start-and-stop-conditions.html).

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thanks. It really helps.